# addClass(), The class is added, but the CSS don't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

When the page is scrolled down. I am trying to add a class "sticky_logo" to the div.

```
<div id="fixed_logo" > ...</div>

if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
  $("#fixed_logo").addClass("sticky_logo");
}
```

It works, when i scroll down , the class is added, but the characteristics of the class "sticky-logo" don't work, but the CSS of "fixed_logo" still work. How can I activate the CSS of the class, without removing the id.

removeAttr for the id isn't a really good idea, because it will be more complicated after.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alex111kira/ard0gnfu/

Comment: Did you try removing the "class" from your html?

Comment: "CLASS" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute. Either give it a dummy class at the beginning or take it out of the `div`

Comment: I tried, still not working. the class is adde, but the css don't, only the css of the id remains.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle, please? It might have something to do with the properties. Try doing it by adding !Important at the end of the class properties.

Comment: My guess is that the specificity of your other rules are overriding the rules in your sticky_logo class. Please post a complete code example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Is it `sticky_logo` or `sticky-logo`?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/alex111kira/ard0gnfu/  it's sticky_logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS rule for the id is more specific than for the class, and so it is the one which gets applied. Add another class to the logo element that will hold the "normal" styling and then use `.new_class.sticky_logo` for the CSS rule of the sticky state.

Answer (score 1):

An ID selector has higher specificity in css rules ranking than a class selector.

If the css set by the ID selector is over riding the class selector, just combine them in the css:

```css
#fixed_logo{
   /* rules */
}

#fixed_logo.sticky_logo{
   /* these rules will have higher rank */
}
```

The second selector is more specific and will over ride rules set in the first